# Adding a social tag to a page

Tags: sharepoint-2010

In SharePoint when you click on the "I Like It" icon, it sends json to this URL

"_vti_bin/socialdatainternalservice.json/AddQuickTag"

So I wrote a custom script which sends JSON data

```
$("a").click(function(){

      $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "/_vti_bin/socialdatainternalservice.json/AddQuickTag",
        data: '{"targetPage":"http://url/calendar.aspx","title":"Documents - All Documents","quickTagId":0}',
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(msg){
          alert(msg);
        }

      });

          return false; 
});
```

I get an error which simply says "There was an error processing the request." and the error in the log file says "Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/AddQuickTag'."

Is it possible to write a custom script which will post JSON data to this URL and have SharePoint tag a page?

Answer (score 0):

These are the calls that are made for the I Like it functionality

```
/vti_bin/socialdatainternalservice.json/GetNormalizedPageUrl
```

Post

```
{"pageUrl":"http://<web app name>/SitePages/Home.aspx"}
```

Returned

```
{"d":"http://<web app name>/"}
/vti_bin/socialdatainternalservice.json/AddQuickTag
```

Post

```
{"targetPage":"http://<web app name>/","title":"Home - Home","quickTagId":0}
```

Returned

```
{"d":null}
```

I think you need to do the GetNormalized call first.