# Can I "Like" a page in sharepoint without opening it?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

It looks like the like command executes `ctl00_ctl35_AddQuickTag();` which automatically tags the page that you are on. Is it possible to fire this function on a page you are not currently viewing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the answer given in this post: [Adding a social tag to a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701931/adding-a-social-tag-to-a-page), it shows how to call the underlying js function directly.